# how to access a particular column of a particular csv file from many imported csv files

Tags: python, r, csv

Suppose that i have multiple .csv files with columns of same kind . If i wanted to access data of a particular column from a specified .csv file , how is it possible?

All .csv files have been stored in list.data
for ex:

Suppose that here , list.data[1] gives me the first .csv file.
How will i access a column of this file?

I have tried list.data[1]$nameofthecolumn.
But this is giving me null values.
I am not much familiar with R.

> list.data[1]$name1
>   NULL
>
> list.data[1]$name1
>   NULL
>
> list.data[1]
>   $
>   NULL

Comment: try 'head(list.data[1])'

Answer (score 0):

you can use list.data[[1]]$name1